# Request na API da Cielo em PHP usando cURL

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou tentando fazer uma REQUEST da forma abaixo, não estou conseguindo:

```
public function subscribe(){   
$json_url = 'https://apisandbox.cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br/1/sales/';  

$json_string  = json_encode(array(     

    "MerchantOrderId"=>"2014113245231706",
     "Customer" => array(
        "Name" => "Comprador rec programada"
     ),

     "Payment" => array(
        "Type" => "CreditCard",
        "Amount" => 1500,
        "Installments" => 1,
         "SoftDescriptor" => "Assinatura Fraldas"  
     )    


));


$ch = curl_init($json_url);

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json'), CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json_string
    );

    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $result = curl_exec($ch); // Getting jSON result string

    print_r($result);                

    }
```

Comment: Esta faltando os headers, como está documentado em http://developercielo.github.io/Webservice-3.0/?shell#criando-uma-venda-com-autenticação. Veja qual o erro retornado e verifique em http://developercielo.github.io/Webservice-3.0/?shell#http-status-code, o motivo.

Comment: Seria interessante você explicar o porque não esta conseguindo, que erro aparece, o que acontece, de resto, não vejo motivos para -1 na pergunta :)

Answer (score 2):

> Estou APENAS me baseando na documentação disponibilizada em [http://developercielo.github.io/Webservice-3.0/?shell#criando-uma-venda-com-autenticação](http://developercielo.github.io/Webservice-3.0/?shell#criando-uma-venda-com-autentica%C3%A7%C3%A3o), porque utiliza o MESMO endpoint, mas isso não foi mencionado na sua pergunta.

```
curl
--request POST "https://apisandbox.cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br/1/sales/"
--header "Content-Type: application/json"
--header "MerchantId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
--header "MerchantKey: 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789"
--header "RequestId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
--data-binary
{  
   "MerchantOrderId":"2014111903",
   "Customer":{  
      "Name":"Comprador crédito autenticação"
   },
   "Payment":{  
      "Type":"CreditCard",
      "Amount":15700,
      "Installments":1,
      "Authenticate":true,
      "ReturnUrl":"http://www.cielo.com.br",
      "SoftDescriptor":"123456789ABCD",
      "CreditCard":{  
         "CardNumber":"4551870000000183",
         "Holder":"Teste Holder",
         "ExpirationDate":"12/2015",
         "SecurityCode":"123",
         "Brand":"Visa"
      }
   }
}
--verbose
```

Vamos traduzir isso para uma linguagem humana:

- `--request POST` : Indica que é um método POST (estranho... mas ok).
- `--header <conteudo>` : Define os cabeçalhos da requisição para `<conteudo>`.
- `--data-binary <conteudo>` : Define o corpo da requisição para `<conteudo>`.

---

No PHP então faça exatamente a mesma coisa, na mesma ordem, para facilitar:

*Antes de tudo defina o corpo da solicitação e os cabeçalhos:*

```
$cabeçalhos = [
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    'MerchantId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'MerchantKey: 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789',
    'RequestId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
];

$corpo = [
    "MerchantOrderId" => "2014111903",
    "Customer" => [
        "Name" => "Comprador crédito autenticação"
    ],
    "Payment" => [
        "Type" => "CreditCard",
        "Amount" => 15700,
        "Installments" => 1,
        "Authenticate" => true,
        "ReturnUrl" => "http => //www.cielo.com.br",
        "SoftDescriptor" => "123456789ABCD",
        "CreditCard" => [
            "CardNumber" => "4551870000000183",
            "Holder" => "Teste Holder",
            "ExpirationDate" => "12/2015",
            "SecurityCode" => "123",
            "Brand" => "Visa"
        ]
    ]
];
```

*Agora vem a parte do CURL, que é o principal:*

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, [

    // Define o método POST:
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',

    /* Uma outra opção é utilizar:
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    */

    // Define o URL:
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://apisandbox.cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br/1/sales/',

    // Define os cabeçalhos:    
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $cabeçalhos,

    // Define corpo, em JSON:
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($corpo),

    // Habilita o retorno
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true

]);

// Executa:
$resposta = curl_exec($ch);

// Encerra CURL:
curl_close($ch);
```

Agora leia a resposta, pode exemplo:

```
var_dump($resposta);
```

Comment: muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda !!!! show de bola ....

Answer (score 1):

Segue como fiz a requisição via POST na minha integração.

`$request` é um array com as informações de cartão, cliente, etc... como está na documentação mesmo.

```
$data_string = json_encode($request, true);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init("https://apisandbox.cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br/1/sales");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'MerchantId: ' . $MerchantID,
    'MerchantKey: ' . $MerchantKey,
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($result, true);
```

Comment: boa ... muito obrigado!